# Accessing control created dynamically in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a link button which i have created dynamically and added it to a div i want to access this link button in some other function in code behind how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ASP.NET tips: Golden rules for Dynamic Controls.](https://web.archive.org/web/20210124190832/http://geekswithblogs.net/shahed/archive/2008/06/26/123391.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you have defined your control properly(with id) you can access it without a problem in the next request.
But...if you want to access it in the same request, it is not rendered yet, so you need to define your control as a private field in your code behind in order to be able to access it outside your initialization/addToDiv function...

Hope this helps

Marko

Answer (score 1):

As you create it dynamically, you are able to keep reference to this control as your page protected/private member. And access control by this reference.